# Why is "I'm on Team X" correct?

Tags: grammar

I'm a non-native English speaker and I've heard the expression "I'm on Team X" (and not "I'm on X's team") for quite a while now (the first time I heard it was when the Twilight novels were published, where Team Edward and Team Jacob was used to show preference for one of the characters)
An also non-native friend asked me why that was correct and couldn't come up with anything better that "it's just how they speak". It only appears to be valid with the word "team". If you are asked if you prefer white or black shoes, you wouldn't reply "shoes white all the way!".

My question is why "I'm in team X" is used and not "I'm on X's team"?

Comment: I'd guess it derives from labelling teams Team A and Team B (as the answer says, these are names so they are capitalized). Team Edward and Team Jacob are likewise ad hoc and arbitrary. There are lots of places for asking questions about Twilight, so if it did originate in Twilight fandom, that should be your first port of call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is because Edward is not the owner of the Team. Team Edward is the name of the team so you say I'm in Team Edward.
But if the team has a captain, for example, Maria is the captain of one team and you're in that team. The you can say I'm on Maria's team, because Maria is the owner of the team.

Comment: I think is because?//